# R-Plotly: Box Select - Extract x & y Coordinates

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

For my project I need to extract the x and y coordinates of the “Box Select” which I use to select data within a shiny app (as I need to filter according to these values within a time frame). To be more precise - I need the actual coordinates only of the created box, not the x/y values of the selected IDs inside.

[JS - Event Handlers](https://plotly-r.com/js-event-handlers.html) <- I saw here that the event handler has these coordinates (x and y array) and you can see them in the console - but how do I store them dynamically within R?

Thanks already.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
   plotlyOutput('myPlot'),
   )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$myPlot = renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, color = ~Species) %>%
      layout(dragmode = "select")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying around a lot I figured out that the data about the box range is not stored within the event_data of "selected", but they are available in both of "brushed" and "brushing".

Here is my solution to get the range of the created box:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput('myPlot'),
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$myPlot = renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, color = ~Species, 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
      layout(dragmode = "select") %>%
      event_register(event = "plotly_brushed")
  })

  # Drag based selection in plotly graph
  selected_range <- reactiveVal({})
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_brushed"), {
    # storing the values in a reactive value for later use
    selected_range(event_data("plotly_brushed"))

    # alternative method if you want to use it within the same observer/reactive  expression
    #xmin <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$x[1]
    #xmax <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$x[2]
    #ymin <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$y[1]
    #ymax <- event_data("plotly_brushed")$y[2]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the data using the `event_data` call:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput('myPlot'),
    verbatimTextOutput("se")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    output$myPlot = renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, color = ~Species) %>%
            layout(dragmode = "select")
    })

    output$se <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
        d
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey - Thank you for the quick answer. 

I realized my question needs to be clearer. I need the X and Y coordinates of the selection box not of the selected samples. 
A workaround would be to take the min & max of x/y, but that would just "represent" the box and not get the actually coordinates of the box.

Comment: Do you mean in pixels or in terms of the values?

Comment: The actual x/y values of the plot as I need to filter my real data (it is ~ 1 Million data points) according to it. As the plotly performance (even with using toWebGl and partial bundles) is really bad with this large dataset, I have to subset it, filter on these and then use the same selection box on the whole dataset.

Comment: what is curveNumber and plotNumber columns in the output table?

Comment: @LazarusThurston https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-events/

Comment: Thanks, I saw that. However the plotNumber was not matching with my index. Finally `customdata` came to my help.