Store informations from selected data in plotly chart
Below I create a bar plot using plotly. I would like with either the use of Box selection button in the right upper corner of the plot or possibly another way to store the number of periods (bars) selected and the percent difference between them. I do not understand whats the use of Box selection now.
d<-structure(list(DateTime = c("2005-01-03 09:00:00", "2005-01-03 10:00:00", 
"2005-01-03 11:00:00", "2005-01-03 12:00:00", "2005-01-03 13:00:00"
), Open = c(87.0467, 87.0395, 86.5453, 86.5382, 86.4307), High = c(87.2042, 
87.1183, 87.061, 87.0323, 86.4379), Low = c(86.9822, 86.4451, 
86.2947, 86.352, 86.1299), Close = c(87.0323, 86.5453, 86.5382, 
86.4379, 86.1729), Volume = c(6222000L, 15904800L, 5900800L, 
2833300L, 4529900L), Date = c("2005-01-03", "2005-01-03", "2005-01-03", 
"2005-01-03", "2005-01-03"), Weekday = c("Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday"), Day = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Month = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), Year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005), hour = 9:13, 
    minute = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HMS = c("09:00:00", "10:00:00", 
    "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00"), NumericChange = c(-0.021499999999989, 
    -0.487000000000009, -0.00709999999999411, -0.100300000000004, 
    -0.265000000000001), PercentChange = c(-0.0246973710509926, 
    -0.55956236937322, -0.00820379616223424, -0.115902572505557, 
    -0.306578480041742)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
library(plotly)
d%>%
  filter(Date >= Date[1] &
           Date <= Date[5])%>%
  plot_ly(showlegend= FALSE)%>%
  add_trace(type="bar",
            name="Rate of Change", 
            x=~DateTime,
            y= ~PercentChange,
            marker=list(color="#7393B3", opacity=0.8, line = list(color ="#7393B3", width = 2)))%>%
  layout(paper_bgcolor = "Black",
         plot_bgcolor = "Black", 
         font= list(color = "White"),
         yaxis= list(gridcolor="#242424"), 
         hovermode="x unified")


See if this is what youu're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404738/r-plotly-box-select-extract-x-y-coordinates

this is actually a very good solution but how could I find the percent difference between selected points? the difference between y

'd' as the output of event data is a data frame. You can manipulate that frame however you'd like as the output - output$se which is set to verbatimTextOutput in the user interface. When coding, just remember that until you select something d is NULL, so you may need to qualify your changes if(!is.null(d))...
